# Streaming data from Online Radio Channel

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to stream data from any online radio channel.
If yes please let me know the procedure.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by getting the bytes via WebClient and then perform encoding via [MediaStreamSource](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/01/mediastreamsource-sample-with-source-code.aspx). You are using SHOUTcast, therefore the **application/octet-stream** can be obtained by requesting the following URL: http://208.53.158.48:8364/;

Or you might need to fake the user agent to avoid standard HTTP requests.